# Detect when a document has been uploaded or modified in iCloud on iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios, icloud

I am looking for a simple way to detect if a document has been uploaded or modified in iCloud.
The solution I have found for the moment is to poll at given interval the /private/var/Mobile Doc... folder relative to the application and containing iCloud docs, and see if a new document has a recent modified date.

It basically works, but I would like to know if there is some kind of NSNotification, as it is  for example in CoreData+iCloud, or if there are other ways I don't know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [NSMetaDataQuery](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMetadataQuery_Class/Reference/Reference.html) might be what you are looking for. Have a look at the Standford iOS videos (available at iTunes U). The NSMetaDataQuery is used in the Core Data and iCloud-Sessions to monitor the content of an iCloud directory for changes.